# Excel issue - choose next time

Tags: excel

Good afternoon,

I am struggling to fix the issue I'm trying to resolve.
Basically, I have a list which includes time values.
See example:

[image]

As you can see the time values could sometimes be in the same time interval.

That's how I would like it to look at the end result :

[image]

I'm using the following formula to display the start and end result in the next sheet.

=IF(WTW!D4="","",LEFT(TEXT(WTW!D4,"HH"),2)&":00")

How I could achieve that the end result to basically only display the start and end time without duplicating the end results.

As example:
Bad end result
06:00 - 07:00
06:00 - 07:00

Good result
06:00 - 07:00
07:00 - 08:00

The reason for all this is because the start and end hours can change...

Comment: Try using the hour() function. But your 3rd entry in the start column has a start of 07:00 but goes to 08:00 and some are even further apart. like the last two are 13:XX but come out at 17:00.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to sort the unique time by the following formula:

=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet3!$B$3:$B$30, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($Q$1:Q2,Sheet3!$B$3:$B$30), 0)), "")

Just now need to insert somehow so that this also filter one extra criteria in the whole list...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hour function may not be insufficent. Why don't you try:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),0,0)
```

Than right click at the selected cell/range and click **Format Cells**. Click Custom and replace textbox to **hh:mm**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't need to change the time itself. I need to only display unique time from the list. 

06:00 - 07:00
07:00 - 08:00

as often the starting hours starts from 

10:00 - 11:00
So I want to display on the end result the unique hours from the filtered list.